# Algorithm - iterative method

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I'm stuck on an exercise on algorithms, can you help me with this exercise?

> Solve this recursion using iterative method.
>   $$T(n) =  \begin{cases}1 & n=1;\\ 
> 2, & n=2;\\ T(n-2) + n/2,& \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}.$$

I tried to solve this but I got this result:

$$T(n-2\cdot k) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-2\cdot i),$$

$$n-2\cdot k=1\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad k=\frac{n-1}{2}.$$

and I don't know how solve this sum with this $k$?

P.S Sorry on my English I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this type of problem requires backwards substitution starting from $T(n)$.

If $n$ is odd,
$ T(n) \\
= T(n-2) + n/2 \\
=(T(n-4) + (n-2)/2)+n/2 \\
=T(n-4) + (n-2)/2+n/2 \\
=(T(n-6) +(n-4)/2)+ (n-2)/2+n/2 \\
= .... \\
=T(1)+3/2+5/2+...(n-2)/2+(n/2)$

If $n$ is even,
$T(n) \\
= T(n-2) + n/2 \\
=(T(n-4) + (n-2)/2)+n/2  \\
=T(n-4) + (n-2)/2+n/2 \\
=T(n-6) +(n-4)/2+ (n-2)/2+n/2 \\
=.... \\
=T(2)+4/2+6/2...+(n-2)/2+(n/2)$

- $T(0)$ is not defined, so the backward substitution stops at $T(1)$ and $T(2)$ respectively. $T(1)$ and $T(2)$  can be replaced by 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Why does no one upvote this (apparently correct) answer? But can you please rewrite your answer so that the outline and presentation is clearer? Also, $T(0)$ is (apparently) not defined.

Comment: @mathse, I just made a couple of formatting changes. Don't know about others, but, if you think it is the correct answer, you should up-vote it.  :)

Comment: Your answer will be even better when you specify closed-form formulas for $T(n)$ in both cases, e.g., for even $n$: $T(n)=2+2+3+4+\cdots+n/2$ and this sum has a nicer form ...

Comment: Juanito, thanks but how I can write that in expression like formula T(n) = ?